# How do I display a FileStreamResult image in the view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I passed a FileStreamResult image to a View. How do I render the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<img src="<%-- URL to the route which returns the FSR --%>"/>
```